# Is it possible to render over children in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm using `OnRender` event to draw some information about this element (For example: element size, mouse position on element, pixel color under mouse).

But child elements (and even background) overwrites my drawings.

Is there any way to render over child elements? Or is it impossible?

I am sure many people have encountered this problem. But I did not find such a question.

Comment: Why you want to close this question?

Comment: The rendering occurs in the order of the elements in the visual tree. If the element that overrides `OnRender` is a parent, then all its child elements are drawn on top. Drawing the topmost drawing last by overriding a leaf element's `OnRender` could fix the problem. Also take a look at `Adorner` and `AdornerLayer`. Maybe you can use adorners to always render elements on top: [Microsoft Docs: Adorners Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/adorners-overview).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw *on top* of the child elements, you could create a [DrawingVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects) object that you add to the `UIElement` using the `AddVisualChild` method.

Please refer to [Charles Petzold's old MSDN Magazine article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/march/foundations-writing-more-efficient-itemscontrols) for some more information about this.

Comment: Should I call `AddVisualChild` on child element?

Comment: @Denis535: You should call it on the element that you want draw on.